# How do I create a custom playable race?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, class

My friends and I just bought the D&D Starter Set and it only came with a set of pre-created characters. I did a little research (Wikipedia) and found  out that in the core books come a larger set of playable races and classes.

When we bought the game we thought we were going to be able to create our own things like a werewolf paladin or goblin necromancer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* describes how one can modify existing races or create new (playable) ones. Pp. 285-287, specifically.

However, there *are* more official playable races than just those in the Player's Handbook. You may want to take a look at  [What are the playable D&D races in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77247/23970)

---

More broadly, the DMG is largely designed around the concept that D&D should not only allow you to create characters and adventures, but also spells, settings, races, new classes... your own *game*. I view it as a worked example of how to create an RPG in the D&D style. If you're looking for more than the Player's Handbook provides, the DMG likely gives some advice on how to get there.