# Is there a fox people race in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, races

Is there any race that can make let me play as a fox? Either an anthropomorphic fox, or (preferably) a human looking race with fox ears and tail, like an inumimi if you know what that is.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94947/23970