# Is playing an Aarakocra player character currently legal in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, dnd-adventurers-league, aarakocra

I'd like to know if playing an [Aarakocra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/aarakocra) character is currently legal in the D&D 5e Adventurers League.

The Aarakocra race has been in D&D for a while, but is described in detail in 5e in the [*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*](http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf) on page 3:

> This chapter presents three new races to supplement those in the *Player's Handbook* [...] These new options are available when you make a character, provided that your DM allows them in your campaign.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no way for a *starting* character to be an Aarakocra or a Winged Tiefling, because the [Adventurers League Player's Guide v9.1](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) says:

> Races with flight at 1st level *[...]* aren’t available without specific campaign documentation (i.e., certs, etc.).

The referenced "campaign documentation" can be acquired two ways.

1. Season 5 had a DM Quest, "King of the Ordning" that allowed a DM who ran a large portion of the seasonal content to create an Aarakocra with 6,500 XP (or do a complete rebuild of another character).
2. Season 7 has a similar DM Quest, "Death's Master" that allowed a DM who runs a large portion of the season to create an Aarakocra or a Winged Tiefling with 6,500 XP.

No other seasons have had an equivalent DM Quest.

<sub>Season 9 has added an option for tiefling and aasimar characters to gain wings when they reach T2, but that obviously isn't an aarakocra.</sub>

Answer (score 17):

The [Adventurers League Player's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/AL_PG_YP.pdf) says:

> NOTE:
>     A character race that grants a fly speed
>    at 
>   1st
>    level isn’t allowed for D&D Adventurers League 
>   play.

So no, Aarakocra (also Winged Tieflings) are not legal for Adventurers League play.

It's worth noting that this clause has appeared in the ALPG since the Aarakocra was first published; which is to say that it has *never* been legal for AL play.