# Are goliaths Adventurers League legal?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dnd-adventurers-league, goliath

I am going to be playing for the first time and was wondering, are goliaths playable in Adventurers League?

Answer (score 45):

### UPDATE: Adventurers League changed the "+1 rule" in 2021.

An [announcement](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/) from Q1 2021 gives the details.  Basically, Adventurers League players may now simultaneously use any and all of the following sources when choosing player options like races, classes, subclasses, feats, spells, and backgrounds:

- [Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb)
- [Volo's Guide to Monsters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm)
- [Xanathar's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte)
- [Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof)
- [Tasha's Cauldron of Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe)

Other source books may also be available depending on the specifics of the campaign.  The currently active campaigns (as of June 7, 2021) draw from subsets of the following list:

- [Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag)
- [Elemental Evil Player’s Companion](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/player%E2%80%99s-companion)
- [Locathah Rising](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/lr)
- [The Tortle Package](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/the-tortle-package)
- [Eberron: Rising from the Last War](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw)

Note that variants and optional rules must be explicitly allowed, so the variant Human, Half-Elf, and Tiefling races in these books may or may not be available.  The same goes for the customized origins in *Tasha's*.  The best thing to do is to find and follow the character creation guidelines in the Adventurers League Player's Guide specific to your campaign, which can be found [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/ddal_general).

The revised rules have been implemented in these active guides:

- [Historic Campaign Player's Guide (version 1.0)](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/HistoricCampaign_PGv1_0.pdf)
- [Masters Campaign Player's Guide (Dream of the Red Wizards)](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/MALPGv1_0.pdf)
- [Alternate Campaign Player's Guide (Oracle of War)](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/OracleofWar_PGv1_5.pdf)

However, the active [Seasonal Campaign Player's Guide (Plague of Ancients)](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/AL_PGv10_3.pdf) remains the version from September 15, 2020.  It's likely to be updated when the next Seasonal Campaign begins.

The active [Guidelines for Using TCoE in Adventurers League Play](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/dnd_tcoe_alguidance.pdf) also predate the change, so must be revised.

### Goliaths

Regarding the original question, *Volo's Guide to Monsters* is on the list of source books available for all Adventurers League campaigns.  Because goliaths are described therein, they're allowed in Adventurers League play.

However, under the updated rules, choosing a goliath no longer prevents the use of character options from other allowed source books like *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.

Comment: Okay, the bounty-attention almost got it there (top spot). Leaving this comment as a marker in the sand, curious how long it'll take this correct answer to naturally overtake my deprecated one =)

Comment: @nitsua60 looks like it has!

Comment: @StopBeingEvil only six months, not too bad in the scale of things....

Answer (score 38):

*This answer was valid 2017-2021; see [gto's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/187935/23970) for an update.*

---

### Yes, as long as you abide by the "+1 rule."

The [DDAL Player's guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources) "Character Creation" section says, in part:

> All of the races and classes presented in the *Player's Handbook* plus **one** other resource from those listed below are available to build your character. (p.2, emphasis in the original)

Pertinent to you, both the Elemental Evil Player's Companion and *Volo's Guide to Monsters* are listed; those're [where you can find goliath to play](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77248/23970).

So you can choose to grab a goliath from either of those sources. Note, however, that locks *out* the possibility of using any character options from *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* or *Xanathar's Guide to Everything,* for instance.

Comment: FYI, a 2021 revision to the AL rules replaces the "PHB+1" requirement with a restriction to selected core books.  You may now simultaneously pull from Xanathar's Guide to Everything and Volo's Guide to Monsters.  (The Elemental Evil Player's Companion is only sometimes allowed.)

Comment: @gto that's good to know--I've barely played AL since the XP-->AP/gold-->TP thing, and now they've shuffled things around even more, I suppose. If you think that nuance could be edited into this answer pretty seamlessly, please go ahead and do so. But if, as I suspect, it'd really be a re-work of the whole answer, can I suggest that you post a new/current answer, I'll drop a "deprecated ca. $DATE" note on this one, and I'll bounty yours?

Comment: I have provided an updated answer, as requested.