# Is there a playable githyanki available?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, gith

Are Githyanki a playable race in D&D 5e?

Comment: Related: [What are the playable D&D races in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e)

Comment: Scoping this to "what homebrew for this exists?" makes is super-mega-ultra-too-broad, because it's a potentially unending list question. It's also opinion based which homebrew to recommend, so that's two close reasons it checks. Adding a "or this other question" just makes it even broader.

Comment: @SkyPaul Please do not answer in comments

Comment: @NautArch Sorry. It is closed though so I can't post an answer.

Comment: @SkyPaul Yes, so the process is to reopen it. Not to bypass the process and post in comments.

Answer (score 11):

**There is an Unearthed Arcana Githyanki.**

While it's not official, there was an Unearthed Arcana, which is the closest thing we have to an official githyanki. 
https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Eladrin-Gith.pdf

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is out of date. See the duplicate answer for information on the official playable Gith race.