# What are all the background features in the Player's Handbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, background

Looking to find a comprehensive list of the background features in the PHB so that it’s easier to reference and customize a player background.

Comment: Are you talking about the name of each background or are you looking for essentially a spreadsheet of skill bonuses, languages & tool proficiencies and items granted? The former could be answered. The latter would seem to be a copyright violation to me.

Comment: The former is sufficient.

Comment: I think the reason you are getting downvotes is because this question effectively amounts to "Read the book for me" or even "Read the book at me"

Comment: Hey all, this question doesn't seem too broad to me and it already has an answer which demonstrates that its scope is very narrow. If you don't like the question, that's fine, that is what downvotes are for. Personally, I'm not seeing anything close-worthy about it though.

Comment: Quoting the tooltip/hover text on the downvote button: "_This question does not show any research effort_". I'm aware that this text is probably originally worded to suit SO, but even so, this question is just "give me a list", and as Oblivious Sage says, anyone with the PHB can easily answer this themselves. Just because lots of lazy people exist on the internet, enough to influence Google's autofill, doesn't justify no research effort here. At the very least, this question might have been received more favourably if you had provided an answer yourself (too late for that now, of course)...

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'd agree that it lacks a clear problem to be solved, but so do other well-received posts ([for example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e-and-where-can-i-find-them)) in a similar vein. While asking about an actual problem is vastly preferred and helps in many cases to answer the question more effectively, I wouldn't say that I would make it required for a question to be on-topic here. I can always be off-base, but it seems like this is a case where downvote is the appropriate tool over closure for those that disapprove of it.

Comment: I’ve achieved the popular question badge for this question, I can say objectively - it’s valued by the wider gaming community - while not by stack insiders.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds?filter-name=&filter-source=2) (this one is filtered by PHB) to obtain all the available backgrounds there, or modify it for other sources as well.

The available features (and corresponding backgrounds) from the PHB are:

- Shelter of the Faithful (Acolyte)
- False Identity (Charlatan)
- Criminal Contact (Criminal / Spy)
- By Popular Demand (Entertainer / Gladiator)
- Rustic Hospitality (Folk Hero)
- Guild Membership (Guild Artisan / Guild Merchant)
- Discovery (Hermit)
- Retainers (Knight)
- Position of Privilege (Noble)
- Wanderer (Outlander)
- Bad Reputation (Pirate)
- Researcher (Sage)
- Ship's Passage (Sailor)
- Military Rank (Soldier)
- City Secrets (Urchin)