# Are the Revenant rules official? If so which book are they in?

Tags: dnd-5e

Critical Role spoiler ahead:

> In Critical Role, Campaign 1, Vax becomes a Revenant.

I have found the rules for this listed on Unearthed Arcana and homebrew sites but have the rules for Revenants been officially published as of yet? and [What are the playable D&D races in 5e, and where can I find them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e-and-where-can-i-find-them). lists as below:

> Revenant (UA: "Gothic Heroes"), actually a subrace that can be applied to human, dragonborn, or tiefling

Does this, therefore, mean that Revenants are not official (come under the unofficial/official that UA rules do until they are published officially in a paid for book)

Comment: This doesn't specifically answer my question no, the answer provided states again the same source for Revenant as I have quoted, Unearthed Archana, as this is not strictly considered official then am I to assume that Revenant have never gone beyond being unofficial?

Comment: You assume correctly (it would be listed in one of the official sources otherwise).

Comment: I'm really not sure what more you're looking for than what is covered in the linked question. That is the Stack's "canonical" list of playable races. The Revenant is listed, it's only listed as UA which means it's not been officially published. How is that not a specific answer to your question?