# Do I combine assets from one's Class with one's Background?

Tags: dnd-5e, background

I've hardly played any D&D, and I'm about to act as a group's DM very soon. I've been doing my 'homework' of course, but I'm running out of time and have difficulties grasping some concepts still.

To the actual question:

Do I combine assets from one's Class with one's Background? When looking into the Class and Background sections while creating a character, you are entitled to some assets.

For example, if I was to create a Bard I am entitled to "(a) a lute or (b) any other musical instrument", and as a character with an "Entertainer" Background I am entitled to "A musical instrument (one of your choice)". So do I get two instruments, or just one?

Thanks, I know this is an awfully noobish question.

Comment: related: [Which equipment do I choose when creating a character in D&D 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84035/23970)

Answer (score 2):

## You receive equipment based on a combination of your class and background.

You receive equipment from your class and from your background, in your example you would get two instruments.

## Or you get gold pieces and buy everything on your own

Alternatively you could just get starting wealth based on your class and buy all of your equipment on your own.

It says so in the PHB p. 143 under the point "Starting Equipment".