# What are the official, WotC-published classes and subclasses in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, archetype

There aren't too many published materials that contain official classes (classes here meaning sub-classes and archetypes included) but they are scattered resources.

**What are the official, 1st-party, WotC-published classes and which resources are they found in?**

For the purposes of this question "unofficial", playtest material such as Unearthed Arcana is excluded and will be asked as a separate question.

---

Related questions:

- [What are the playable D&D races in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e)
- [Where do I find the "official" rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e)
- [Is it necessary to purchase all the D&D 5th books to have access to all character classes etc.?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63297/is-it-necessary-to-purchase-all-the-dd-5th-books-to-have-access-to-all-characte) (even though the answer to this linked question just happens to more-or-less answer this question, they *are* different questions)

and meta discussion and approval for this question [here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8090/is-a-question-asking-what-wotc-published-dd-5e-classes-are-available-a-viable)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Sources:

- [*Basic Rules*](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=22) (BR), Chapter 3: Classes
- [*System Reference Document*](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=8) (SRD), p. 8-55
- (Note: [D&D Beyond's "Basic Rules" listing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) is actually an
  inclusive combination of the Basic Rules PDF and the SRD)
- [*Player's Handbook*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook) (PHB), Chapter 3: Classes
- [*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide) (SCAG), Chapter 4: Classes
- [*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/xanathars-guide-everything) (XGtE), Chapter 1: Character Options
- [*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/tashas-cauldron-everything) (TCoE), Chapter 1: Character Options
- [*Van Richten’s Guide to Ravenloft*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/van-richtens-guide-ravenloft) (VRGtR), Chapter 1: Character Creation
- [*Fizban's Treasury of Dragons*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/treasury-dragons) (FToD), Chapter 1: Character Creation
- [*Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/guildmasters-guide-ravnica) (GGtR), p. 25-27
- [*Mythic Odysseys of Theros*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/mythic-odysseys-theros) (MOoT), Chapter 1 > Subclass options
- [*Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/247882/Wayfinders-Guide-to-Eberron-5e) (WGtE), Appendix D
- [*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/eberron) (E:RftLW), p. 54-63
- [*Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/wildemount) (EGtW), p. 182-186
- [*Dungeon Master's Guide*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dungeon-masters-guide) (DMG), p. 96-97

---

#### Artificer (WGtE, E:RftLW, TCoE)

**Artificer Specialists:**

- Alchemist (WGtE, E:RftLW, TCoE)
- Armorer (TCoE)
- Artillerist (E:RftLW, TCoE)
- Battle Smith (E:RftLW, TCoE)

#### Barbarian (SRD, PHB)

**Primal Paths:**

- Path of the Berserker (SRD, PHB)
- Path of the Totem Warrior (PHB, SCAG)
- Path of the Battlerager (SCAG)
- Path of the Ancestral Guardian (XGtE)
- Path of the Storm Herald (XGtE)
- Path of the Zealot (XGtE)
- Path of the Beast (TCoE)
- Path of Wild Magic (TCoE)

#### Bard (SRD, PHB)

**Bard Colleges:**

- College of Lore (SRD, PHB)
- College of Valor (PHB)
- College of Glamour (XGtE)
- College of Swords (XGtE)
- College of Whispers (XGtE)
- College of Eloquence (MOoT, TCoE)
- College of Creation (TCoE)
- College of Spirits (VRGtR)

#### Cleric (BR, SRD, PHB)

**Cleric Domains:**

- Knowledge Domain (PHB)
- Life Domain (BR, SRD, PHB)
- Light Domain (PHB)
- Nature Domain (PHB)
- Tempest Domain (PHB)
- Trickery Domain (PHB)
- War Domain (PHB)
- Arcana Domain (SCAG)
- Forge Domain (XGtE)
- Grave Domain (XGtE)
- Order Domain (GGtR, TCoE)
- Peace Domain (TCoE)
- Twilight Domain (TCoE)
- Death Domain (DMG)<sup>1</sup>

#### Druid (SRD, PHB)

**Druid Circles:**

- Circle of the Land (SRD, PHB)
- Circle of the Moon (PHB)
- Circle of Dreams (XGtE)
- Circle of the Shepherd (XGtE)
- Circle of Spores (GGtR, TCoE)
- Circle of Stars (TCoE)
- Circle of Wildfire (TCoE)

#### Fighter (BR, SRD, PHB)

**Fighter Archetypes:**

- Champion (BR, SRD, PHB)
- Battle Master (PHB)
- Eldritch Knight (PHB)
- Purple Dragon Knight (SCAG)
- Arcane Archer (XGtE)
- Cavalier (XGtE)
- Samurai (XGtE)
- Echo Knight (EGtW)
- Psi Warrior (TCoE)
- Rune Knight (TCoE)

#### Monk (SRD, PHB)

**Monastic Traditions:**

- Way of the Open Hand (SRD, PHB)
- Way of Shadow (PHB)
- Way of the Four Elements (PHB)
- Way of the Long Death (SCAG)
- Way of the Sun Soul (SCAG, XGtE)
- Way of the Drunken Master (XGtE)
- Way of the Kensei (XGtE)
- Way of Mercy (TCoE)
- Way of the Astral Self (TCoE)
- Way of the Ascendant Dragon (FToD)

#### Paladin (SRD, PHB)

**Sacred Oaths:**

- Oath of Devotion (SRD, PHB)
- Oath of the Ancients (PHB)
- Oath of Vengeance (PHB)
- Oath of the Crown (SCAG)
- Oath of Conquest (XGtE)
- Oath of Redemption (XGtE)
- Oath of Glory (MOoT, TCoE)
- Oath of the Watchers (TCoE)
- Oathbreaker (DMG)<sup>1</sup>

#### Ranger (SRD, PHB)

**Ranger Archetypes:**

- Hunter (SRD, PHB)
- Beast Master (PHB)
- Gloom Stalker (XGtE)
- Horizon Walker (XGtE)
- Monster Slayer (XGtE)
- Fey Wanderer (TCoE)
- Swarmkeeper (TCoE)
- Drakewarden (FToD)

#### Rogue (BR, SRD, PHB)

**Roguish Archetypes:**

- Assassin (PHB)
- Thief (BR, SRD, PHB)
- Arcane Trickster (PHB)
- Mastermind (SCAG, XGtE)
- Swashbuckler (SCAG, XGtE)
- Inquisitive (XGtE)
- Scout (XGtE)
- Phantom (TCoE)
- Soulknife (TCoE)

#### Sorcerer (SRD, PHB)

**Sorcerous Origins:**

- Draconic Bloodline (SRD, PHB)
- Wild Magic (PHB)
- Storm Sorcerer (SCAG, XGtE)
- Divine Soul (XGtE)
- Shadow Magic (XGtE)
- Aberrant Mind (TCoE)
- Clockwork Soul (TCoE)

#### Warlock (SRD, PHB)

**Otherworldly Patrons:**

- The Archfey (PHB)
- The Fiend (SRD, PHB)
- The Great Old One (PHB)
- The Undying (SCAG)
- The Celestial (XGtE)
- The Hexblade (XGtE)
- The Fathomless (TCoE)
- The Genie (TCoE)
- The Undead (VRGtR)

#### Wizard (BR, SRD, PHB)

**Arcane Traditions:**

- School of Abjuration (PHB)
- School of Conjuration (PHB)
- School of Divination (PHB)
- School of Enchantment (PHB)
- School of Evocation (BR, SRD, PHB)
- School of Illusion (PHB)
- School of Necromancy (PHB)
- School of Transmutation (PHB)
- Bladesinging (SCAG, TCoE)
- War Magic (XGtE)
- Chronurgy Magic (EGtW)
- Graviturgy Magic (EGtW)
- Order of Scribes (TCoE)

---

D&D Beyond has a nicely formatted reference for all of the available classes/races/etc. Subclass and subrace information is also available by looking at the parent class or race's details. It should be noted that the free access materials do not include much outside of the D&D Basic Rules. They do offer other books' content, but that content must be purchased separately.

[D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com)

[Classes Page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes)

[Races Page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races)

---

<sup>1</sup> These subclasses are included in the DMG and can be used only with the consent of the DM because they are generally made to be used for NPCs only or only in special DM-granted circumstances. However, the DM may choose to make these subclass options more generally available.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88275/discussion-on-answer-by-purple-monkey-what-are-the-official-wotc-published-clas).

Comment: If you're include Explorer's Guide to Wildermont, you might as well include the Planeswalker's Guide articles. They're both about as official, in that they were published by WotC but not written by the DnD team.