# Which book contains The Celestial warlock patron?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, product-identification

I was wondering which book the Celestial Path for warlock is in? I have the Player's Handbook and as far as I could tell it's not in there.

So what book is it in? An exact page # would be wicked though unnecessary.

Answer (score 11):

The official published version is in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* on page 54.

For future reference, see [this complete list of published subclasses](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125278/what-are-the-official-wotc-published-classes-and-subclasses-in-5e), elsewhere on this site.

Answer (score 4):

First appeared in Unearthed Arcana, and later published on page 54 of Xanatar's Guide to Everything.