# Is the Fencer subclass for fighters from the Giger's website homebrew content?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, fighter, archetype

So, I was looking up Fighter subclasses in D&D 5e, and I came across a website called [Giger's 5e D&D](http://gdnd.wikidot.com). In it there is a subclass called [Fencer](http://gdnd.wikidot.com/fightersubclass:fencer), and I was wondering if it's Unearthed Arcana or pure Homebrew.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: A [meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/how-should-this-question-about-content-in-a-site-that-includes-piracy-be-handled) has been opened regarding this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It is homebrew.

There is no official subclass (or any feature actually) called Fencer in any officially published book or UA. So this must be a homebrew created by someone outside of that.

As for citations, I did a deep search of all the UA material for the term "fencer" and it never comes up as a class option. A similar search on D&DBeyond also turns up nothing.

Comment: Might it be worth linking back to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125278/14878) in your answer for future reference on official (sub)classes?

Answer (score 1):

This subclass for the fighter is a homebrew. Someone talked about making a fencer homebrew subclass on reddit, however I do not know if they made this one. The subclass is not listed in any official D&D 5e books so it is a homebrew.

https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/a40mb8/a_fighter_subclass_the_fencer/

Comment: Note that that reddit post is a completely different subclass. It appears to be unrelated to the one OP is referring to.