# What are the official languages available to players?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, languages

The D&D 5th Edition *Player's Handbook* lists some languages on page 123, giving players with characters who can choose a language a number of choices.

There are other sources of player-choosable languages across a variety of published materials.

**What are the official WotC-published languages available to players and which resources are they published in?**

Related questions:

- [What are the playable D&D races in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e)
- [Where do I find the "official" rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e)
- [What are the official, WotC-published classes and subclasses in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125278/what-are-the-official-wotc-published-classes-and-subclasses-in-5e)
- [Is it necessary to purchase all the D&D 5th books to have access to all character classes etc.?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63297/is-it-necessary-to-purchase-all-the-dd-5th-books-to-have-access-to-all-characte)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Sources where they first became available to players:*
PHB = Player's Handbook
MM = Monsters Manual
MToF = Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes
SCAG = Swords Coast Adventurer's Guide
VGtM = Volo's Guide to Monsters
GGtR = Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica
WGtE = Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron
DMG = Dungeon Master's Guide
EGtW = Explorer's Guide to Wildemount

#### Standard Languages:

- Common (PHB)
- Dwarvish (PHB)
- Elvish (PHB)
- Giant (PHB)
- Gnomish (PHB)
- Goblin (PHB)
- Halfling (PHB)
- Orc (PHB)

#### Standard Languages (Ravnica):

- Abyssal (PHB)
- Celestial (PHB)
- Common (PHB)
- Draconic (PHB)
- Elvish (PHB)
- Giant (PHB)
- Goblin (PHB)
- Kraul (GGtR)
- Loxodon (GGtR)
- Merfolk (GGtR)
- Minotaur (GGtR)
- Sphinx (MM)
- Sylvan (PHB)
- Vedalken (GGtR)

#### Exotic Languages:

- Abyssal (PHB)
- Celestial (PHB)
- Draconic (PHB)
- Deep Speech (PHB)
- Infernal (PHB)
- Primodial (PHB)
- Aquan
- Auran
- Ignan
- Terran
- Sylvan (PHB)
- Undercommon (PHB)

#### Race/Class-Specific Languages:

- Aarakocra (MM)
- Druidic (PHB)
- Gith (MToF)
- Thieves' Cant (PHB)

#### Forgotten Realms Human Languages (requires GM permission):

(All in SCAG)

- Dambrathan
- Bedine
- Alzhedo
- Chondathan
- Damaran
- Waelan
- Guran
- Halruaan
- Illuskan
- Roushoum
- Chessentan
- Mulhorandi
- Untheric
- Thayan
- Rashemi
- Shaaran
- Shou
- Tuigan
- Turmic
- Uluik

#### Eberron's Common Languages

- Common (PHB)
- Dwarvish (PHB)
- Elvish (PHB)
- Giant (PHB)
- Goblin (PHB)
- Orc (dead language, PHB)
- Infernal (PHB)
- Riedran (WGtE)
- Quori (WGtE)

#### Monstrous Languages ([available via Favored Enemy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125868/41726) or Training):

- Blink Dog (MM)
- Bullywug (MM)
- Giant Eagle (MM)
- Giant Elk (MM)
- Giant Owl (MM)
- Gnoll (MM)
- Grell (MM)
- Grung (VGtM)
- Hook Horror (MM)
- Kruthik (MToF)
- Modron (MM)
- Otyugh (MM)
- Sahuagin (MM)
- Slaad (MM)
- Sphinx (MM)
- Thri-kreen (MM)
- Tlincalli (VGtM)
- Troglodyte (MM)
- Umber Hulk (MM)
- Vegepygmy (VGtM)
- Winter Wolf (MM)
- Worg (MM)
- Yeti (MM)

#### Book of Vile Darkness

- Dark Speech (DMG)

#### Wildemount's common languages

- Zemnian (EGtW)
- Marquesian (EGtW)
- Naush (EGtW)

Comment: @PinkSweetener in the basic rules: the beginning of the backgrounds section under the Additional Languages section references the Languages portion of Chapter 4 which is limited to standard and exotic languages (unless a different language is "common in your campaign" which I doubt the monstrous languages are)

Comment: [*Eberron: Rising from the Last War* has a new/updated pair of language tables.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/welcome-to-eberron#Languages) The common languages are Common, Dwarvish, Elvish, Giant, Gnomish, Goblin, Halfling, and Riedran (Gnomish and Halfling are missing from your list of "common Eberron languages"). The exotic languages are Celestial, Daelkyr, Draconic, Infernal, Orc, Primordial, Quori, and Sylvan (you have Orc, Infernal, and Quori included in your list of "common Eberron languages", and haven't listed the other exotic ones at all).

Comment: The organization of the language list seems even stranger now that several more setting books are out: besides [Eberron](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/welcome-to-eberron#Languages) and [Ravnica](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/ggtr/welcome-to-ravnica#Languages), there's also [Wildemount](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw/welcome-to-wildemount#Languages) in the world of Exandria (it basically says "everything PHB/MM is fair game", and just adds 3 new languages on top of that) and now [Theros](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/welcome-to-theros#Languages).

Comment: I'm not sure how best to integrate these additions. You seem to start with the PHB's Standard Languages table, followed by Ravnica's Standard Languages, then the PHB's Exotic Languages, then 2 languages listed only for a certain PC race and their monster counterparts alongside 2 languages only listed for individual class features, then SCAG's human languages, then Eberron's Common Languages, then the languages that only appear in monster statblocks, and then the 1 language from an artifact in the DMG. The organization seems all over the place, and leaves out non-FR exotic languages entirely.

Comment: One approach is to split out the monstrous languages into a separate question, since that may keep increasing with every new monster published (rather than only having to update when a setting book is released). Alternately, it may be worth editing the question to focus on FR specifically, and editing the answer accordingly - but that might change its scope beyond what the OP wanted... You may also want to reformat the answer so there's not just 1 language per line - it makes the answer overly long (vertically). You could combine each current section into 1 bullet/paragraph each.

Comment: Technically the Exotic Languages in the PHB also require DM permission.

Comment: Note Thieves' Cant isn't actually a language. Presumably you could speak the cant in giant elk if you were so inclined.