# What language do undead speak?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, undead, ranger, languages

I really need help with creating my ranger. For my "**favored enemy**," I chose **undead**, but I don't know what language they speak (if they speak one at all). Do I just look for a single undead (e.g. a Ghoul speaks Common) and say that is what *all* undead speak? Please help me.

Answer (score 11):

### Undead don't have a dedicated language

In general, they speak languages they knew in life. Here's a couple of examples:

> #### [Zombie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie)
>
> **Languages** understands the languages it knew in life but can't speak

> ### [Vampire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire)
>
> **Languages** the languages it knew in life

> #### [Skeleton](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/skeleton)
>
> **Languages** Understands all languages it knew in life but can't speak

There are plane-specific undead like [Death Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/death-knight) which speaks the corresponding language (Abyssal in this case). Most undead usually understand or speak Common.

Since Favored Enemy still has to grant additional language proficiency, the player is usually free to choose any non-secret language people in the game world speak. The exact list depends on the setting and your DM.

See also [If a Ranger chooses "fey" as their Favored Enemy, what languages can they choose from?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125868/)

Comment: So, basically, I can choose any language I want that I don't already have?

Comment: @LoganTaylor You might want to upvote my answer if you feel it is useful, but wait for a day or two before accepting, since a better answer might appear. By accepting my answer you reduce the chance of other people answering.

Comment: Thanks, @enkryptor! I really appreciate your help, but I can't upvote yet. I don't have any reputation yet.

Comment: @LoJaTa50963 only your DM knows if you can choose *any* language. At least you should add *some* language, otherwise it would be meaningless nerfing of the feature

Comment: I know, but I really think you are very kind to help me so much lately. I really appreciate your help! Also, can we be friends (just in a group I made, that is...)?

Comment: @LoJaTa50963 I don't understand what group are you talking about. You can add me on discord if you wish — enkryptor#7124